# Is there a way to make an external service as a subscriber for pubsub model using spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I am new to spring integration , i am trying to achieve the following through spring integration:
there are 3 micro services A,B,C  , based on some event i would want to publish a message to spring integration channel to which services B and C should have subscribed.
i am unable to figure out a way to make an external service as subscriber.
please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a message broker such as RabbitMQ, Kafka, JMS etc. to communicate between external services.

Or, you could connect them explicitly using TCP channel adapters or gateways.

Read [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/).

See [the samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples).

Comment: HI Gary,
Thanks for the reply
i am using JMS active MQ  where i have created a producer channel which pushes data to the JMS active mq and in another service i have created a cosnumer channel , now the only problem is if i create 2 services which have consumer channel, only one of them reads the data in a load balanced way.
i am following link
https://codenotfound.com/spring-jms-integration-example.html
done few changes like i changed direct channel to pubsub channel and moved the consumer code to another microservice

Comment: ActiveMQ has a `prefetch` option, to improve performance, which (IIRC) defaults to 1000; so that may cause all the messages to be sent to one of the consumers. See https://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html